# Ionic card image in card header is automatically resized when a text is displayed

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have these 2 cards displayed on page:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card class="offersCard">
        <ion-card-header>
            <b>Company Name</b>
      <br/>
      <b>Dealer</b>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft imgStyle">
          Image
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight">

          <div>
          Offer Descriptions:
          <br/>
          Offer Descriptions:... 
          Offer Descriptions:...
          Offer Descriptions:... 
          Offer Descriptions:...
          Offer Descriptions:...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft alignTxt">
          Price:
          d
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight fullBtn">
          <button ion-button primary>CHECK OFFER</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card class="offersCard">
        <ion-card-header>
            <b>Company Name</b>
      <br/>
      <b>Dealer</b>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft imgStyle">
          Image
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight">

          <div>
          Offer Descriptions:
          <br/>
          Offer Descriptions:
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft alignTxt">
          Price:
          d
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight fullBtn">
          <button ion-button primary>CHECK OFFER</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

When the card has a big text as description, it gets resized into left instead of keeping the same height and weight specified in the scss:

```
.offersCard{
  .floatRight{
    float: right;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 4em;
  }
  .floatLeft{
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  div{
    display: flex;
  }
  .imgStyle{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .fullBtn{

    float: right;
    margin-right: 0em
  }
  .alignTxt{
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
}
```

[image]

in addition, my "Check Offer" button is set to float to right, but it stays in the middle of the card.

Here is a full working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rkavsl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-acboxj

You need to specify width to floatRight

```
.floatRight{
    float: right;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 2em;
    width: calc(100% - 150px - 2em);
}
```

Comment: and for the button ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xqm7sa

You need to specify justify property to fullBtn

```
.fullBtn{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help